# Page Transition between pages

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a question i have been searching for how do these websites do page transition like when i click on a button or on a link it move to the next page with no time or with animations like these websites :

[First site](http://dogstudio.co)

[Second site](http://richardmattka.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Single Page Applications (SPA). Actually, they don't go to some other pages when you click a link. They change the URL and load a view to DOM accordingly. You can use one of Vue.js, React.js, Angular.js, and Svelte.js (I guess) to create those types of pages.

Comment: does it good to create a php website or offline web applications ?

Comment: They are pure javascript frameworks. No PHP with them in frontend. I don't know what is offline web application.

Comment: offline web application like doing a financial application for calculations.
what is the best for your opinion angular or react or vue to learn ?

Comment: Pretty much everything can be done with those frameworks as long as you use javascript.

Comment: i guess i'll go for angular then because its popular one ^^

Comment: Angular is the worst choice by far and it's definitely not so popular anymore. With Angular 2, it lost everyone to React, and now, Vue is growing. React is the most popular one, and Vue is the easiest one. I don't know too much about Svelte. I strongly suggest you pick Vue if you're a freelancer or full-stack developer. If you want to work at a company, pick React, because most company looking for React developers. Of course those things change quickly.

Comment: i'm trying to be a fullstack developer to make full website and web application alone and yea i see alot of software companies using react , i guess i'm going to pick react as first framework then move to vue then
Thanks for your answer Bulent Akgul :)